# Why are my symbols not displayed correctly in the legend and after a PDF-Export?

Tags: qgis, symbology, qgis-2

I work with QGIS 2.0.1.

I have two problems with the representation of symbols.

The first problem is that after I selected a symbol with the type: font and adjust the size of the symbol with the unit: map units, the symbol is not displayed completely within the Legend.

Is this a general problem that the icon size is also scaled within the legend?

[image: SymbolOVERVIEW]

Legend:

[image: Legend]

---

The next problem is that when I want to export my map to a PDF file the Symbols are not displayed correctly.

The icon consists of two components.

I have tried two different versions but the result was not useful.

Here are the two variants i have tried:

1. Symbol as font and white background as a Font.
2. Symbol as font and white background as a simple symbol with a square.

In QGIS both variants provide a correct representation.

But the result was similar for both variants. The Symbol components are shifted from each other in the PDF-Export.

Symbols in PDF-Export File:

[image: SymbolsPDF]

Symbols in QGIS

[image: SymbolsQGIS]

Comment: The first problem is just a limitation of the legend. Might be fixed at some stage in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for your second problem:

Draw the symbol in Inkscape and save it as a SVG file (to be safe convert the text field into a geometry). You can add SVG symbols in QGIS and they survive the export intact.

Edit: Can't upload my SVG symbol here because the file format is banned.

Edit 2: Download my pretty W:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65175676/Kreis_mit_W.svg

Comment: Your link is 404.